Azure devops grouping User Stories based on their parents
we are currently working on reporting on azure devops and we are facing the problem that you cant group the query by their parent, what we want to achieve is that we want to calculate how much work is done based on the project base! So we could see how many User Stories done in each epic and Episode,, just to get an overall look at the project and how much we have achieved.
Is that possible to do on Azure devops internally without using PowerBI??
Thanks
